# Is there a way to align a widget to the far right of a row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a row in Flutter with two widgets. I'm trying to keep the first widget centered in the middle of the screen and the second widget forced to the far right of the screen.

I've tried using Spacer(). This results in the app returning a blank screen.

I've also tried using Expanded. This sends the second widget off the screen completely.

Trying mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween did not seem to have any effect.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              child: new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                },
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Profile',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 50.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.settings,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: 30.0,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => OnBoarding()),
                                        );
                                      }),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a `Row` with an `Expanded` child that contains a `Stack`. Centre your text with `Center` and position the icon with `Positioned`, like so:

```dart
[...]
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(height: 40.0),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(...),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 8,
                child: IconButton(...),
[...]
```

Comment: As a note, this errored on hot reload, but gave the desired result when rerunning the app.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint on expanded.  So I had a Row with 4 items in it and I wanted the last item to be pushed as far right as possible.  I didn't have any main axis alignment.  I was able to make the 3rd widget (text) inside Expaneded, and that made the 4th last widget in the Row pushed all the way to the end.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

Simply just add `Spacer()` between your main text and the Icon you want to the far right.

**For example:**

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    Text(
      'Random test text',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    Spacer(),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert_rounded),
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ],
)
```

I hope this helps you. And I hope the format of the code is readable. Still getting a hang of stackoverflow comments

Answer (score 4):

I did this and worked in my project

```
child:Row(
 **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,**
 children: [
  Icon(MaterialCommunityIcons.comment_outline),
  Text("0"),
  Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
  Text("0"),
  ],
),
```

I needed align Icons and Text at right in Row widget

```
Container(
  child: Row(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end
   children: [ // put your widget list and be happy ]
  )
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByzDV.png)

Comment: This is the most simple and effective solution i found. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a row with this following structure:

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(),
      Container(
        child: Text(
      'Profile',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Lato',
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 50.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
    child:  IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.settings,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 30.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),  
  ]
),
```

what will happen is that the `spaceBetween` property will divide available space equally between the widgets in the row, so I put an empty `Container`, and this will force the `Text` widget to be in the middle of the row and the `IconButton` in the far end as you desire.

I noticed in your code snippet that you have a `Column` with a single `Row` which again contains a single `Column` , you should eliminate this redundancy to optimize your code and make it easier to debug:

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Unfortunately, MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween did not have any discernible effect to the code.

Comment: I forgot to add `Containers` to wrap each `child`, let me add them and try again

Comment: I just wanted to tell you so

Comment: Sorry, I tried again and I was unable to detect any changes.

Comment: remove the `child` property before your `GestureDetector` you can't put that when nested inside `children` list

Comment: Oh sorry, there is an additional container I accidentally omitted that surrounds the GestureDetector. I removed the contents of that additional container so as to save space.

Answer (score 1):

Imo the easiest way to do this is to create a row with 2 children: The first child is an Expanded Row with all your "main" widgets. The second child is your widget which must be aligned to the end.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [...mainWidgets...],
      ),
    ),
   ...endWidget...
  ],
),
```

Note that Expanded is space-greedy. If you use e.g. MainAxisAlignment.center for your Expanded Row, then your children are drawn across the whole avialable width. If this is not to your liking, Id suggest to wrap the Expanded-**Row** (not Expanded) inside a Container with "constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500)". Obviously Expanded shouldnt be Constrained.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the mainAxisAlignment of the row to mainAxisAlignment.center?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried and didn't detect any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Achieve using `Expanded` & `Align` like below inside `Row`:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    ...some other widgets,
    Expanded(
      //Expanded will help you to cover remaining space of Row
      flex: 1,
      child: Align(
        //Align with alignment.centerRight property will move the child to righteous inside Expanded
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

> Note, the `Expanded` has to be just inside the `Row children: <Widget>[]`,
> othewise suppose you've put the `GestureDetector` inside `Row` `children: <Widget>[]`, and inside `GestureDetector` you have put your `Expanded`, then it won't
> work.

Hope this would help many one.

Comment: I don't know why just someone meanwhile, marked this negative, even this code is unique with widgets (none other similar have used `Align` in answers) & working and used multiple places & times.